# Unresolved external on static data member from another DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dllimport, afx

Consider the following source of `From.dll` library defining the `From` class:

Header:

```
// From.h
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxext.h>

class AFX_EXT_CLASS From
{
    public:
        static const char staticMember[666];
};
```

Implementation:

```
// From.cpp
#include "From.h"

const char From::staticMember[] = "Total Crap";
```

This library static member `staticMember` must be used from the following `To` class, which must also give rise to a DLL (`To.dll`):

Header:

```
// To.h
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxext.h>

class AFX_EXT_CLASS To
{
    public:
        static const char* retExtStatic();
};
```

Implementation:

```
// To.cpp
#include "To.h"
#include "From.h"

const char* To::retExtStatic()
{
    return From::staticMember;
}
```

But I keep getting this `LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char const * const From::staticMember" (?staticMember@From@@2QBDB)` when linking `To.dll`, no matter if it's directly on Visual Studio or if it's a cmake generated nmake:

```
Linking CXX shared library To.dll
   Creating library To.lib and object To.exp
To.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static char const * const From::staticMember" (?staticMember@From@@2QBDB)
To.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The first DLL is compiled and linked allright. The following are the relevant parts of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_definitions (-D_AFXDLL -D_AFXEXT -DPSAPI_VERSION=1)
set (CMAKE_MFC_FLAG 2) # Use MFC in a shared DLL

# FROM
file (GLOB FROM ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/From.cpp)
add_library (From SHARED ${FROM})
target_link_libraries (From)

# TO
file (GLOB TO ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/To.cpp)
add_library (To SHARED ${TO})
target_link_libraries (To From)
```

What am I doing wrong to export this static data member?

Comment: Is your `AFX_EXT_CLASS` appropriately defined when building the second dll for the importing your first dll's class? I.e. Does it change to the correct declspec(dllimport)? From your sample I can really tell.

Comment: Don't use `AFX_EXT_CLASS`, define a macro of your own. Normally, `AFX_EXT_CLASS` expands to `__declspec(dllexport)` when building a DLL, and `__declspec(dllimport)` when building an EXE that consumes it. But here, the consumer is itself a DLL so `AFX_EXT_CLASS` doesn't do the right thing.

Comment: Indeed this is the problem. For this little instance I made up, if I redefine `AFX_EXT_CLASS` before including `From.h` as `__declspec(dllimport)`, I got the linking working properly. But what bugs me now is that I'm almost sure that I got some cases on the project where this scenario works even with both classes declared with `AFX_EXT_CLASS` =( Is there any AFX Windows macro convention/helpers to mark those DLL classes to be used by another DLLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Niall and @Igor Tnadetnik pointed out on comments on the question, when a DLL needs another DLL, it's not safe to include the header file of the DLL to be used if therein the class is declared with `AFX_EXT_CLASS`. In this case, as the client code is also a DLL, `AFX_EXT_CLASS` would be defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` and not as `__declspec(dllimport)` as it should.